# How to reverse json_decode($myJsonString, assoc=true) to get again $myJsonString?

Tags: php, json, json-deserialization

I'm trying to reverse an operation with json_decode to get again the string.

The problem is that I can't do json_encode with the result because the first transformation happened with the parameter `assoc=true`

```
$myJsonString = '{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}';

var_dump(json_decode($json, true));
```

Result:

```
array(5) {
    ["a"] => int(1)
    ["b"] => int(2)
    ["c"] => int(3)
    ["d"] => int(4)
    ["e"] => int(5)
}
```

I would like to recover the String in order to perform `json_decode` without second parameter `assoc=true`

Comment: Use `json_encode`. http://php.net/json_encode

Comment: i really don't understand [your problem](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/8064028b2b069174f5dc33de9b9c01d7b7666059)

Comment: Having the `$assoc` set to true wouldn't stop `json_encode` from properly encoding it again. `$assoc` or not it will still give back the same result with `json_encode`.

Comment: @JamieSterling that is because you are setting the variable to the output of `var_dump`, which returns void (null). See https://3v4l.org/orRCY

Comment: "This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the function [json_encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) to create a json string again (as it returns string):

```
$myJsonString = json_encode($my_decoded_json);
```

Comment: @Charlotte Dunois: Your example is wrong, the function `var_dump()` returns nothing; you have to assign the result of `json_decode()` to the variable `$decoded`

Comment: Nope, `$json` just needs to be replaced with `$MyJsonString`.